# Firefox theme change

Tags: macos, firefox

Is it possible to make Firefox on Mac look like on this screenshot (taken from official Firefox site)? Couldn't find this theme on the website. Is it some kind of platform-specific theme? I am running Firefox 27.0.1 and OSX 10.9.2

p.s. I know question is a bit stupid, but really could not find any tracks of that theme on addons portal

[image]

Comment: Its probably australis.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like this theme is not available anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the new UI on Firefox. So it's not a also a new theme but a new Look and Feel. Currently is available on the [Aurora](https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2014/02/07/test-the-new-firefox-sync-and-customize-the-new-ui-in-firefox-aurora/) update channel which should move to Beta this [week](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Releases#Based_on_Gecko_29).

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the theme [`Australis`](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-br/firefox/addon/australis/).

[image]

Comment: Its also the default in the nightlies, which I was kind of hoping the OP would work out

Comment: Is it possible to use this theme in stable release? I was kind of hoping @JourneymanGeek would work out from my comment that installing alpha browser to change theme is ridiculous

Comment: See my answer. It will be stable *soon*.